# OpenGL SkyBox not showing

Tags: c++, opengl, draw

I'm making a skybox in openGL c++, now I followed some tutorials on skyboxes, I have the image's all set up but my skybox doesn't get drawn at all! (I only see black opengl background)

So here is my code, what can be the problem? I'm looking at it for hours and can't find a thing, I'm new at openGL so if you spot any bad code please do tell! Thanks!

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>


#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#include "imageloader.h"

using namespace std;

//angle of rotation
GLfloat xpos = 0, ypos = 0, zpos = 0, xrot = 0, yrot = 0, angle=0.0;
GLuint _textureId;           //The OpenGL id of the texture
GLuint _skybox[5];
float lastx, lasty;
bool leftMouseButton = false;
float PI = 3.141592654f;

//Makes the image into a texture, and returns the id of the texture
GLuint __loadTexture(Image* image) {
    GLuint textureId;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        GL_RGB,
        image->width, image->height,
        0,
        GL_RGB,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        image->pixels);
    return textureId;
}


GLuint __loadMipmappedTexture(Image *image) {
    GLuint textureId;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                      GL_RGB,
                      image->width, image->height,
                      GL_RGB,
                      GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                      image->pixels);
    return textureId;
}
void initRendering() {
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glShadeModel (GL_SMOOTH); //set the shader to smooth shader

    Image* image = loadBMP("artesis.bmp");
    _textureId = __loadMipmappedTexture(image);
    image = loadBMP("skybox/deep_ft.bmp");
    _skybox[0] = __loadMipmappedTexture(image);
    image = loadBMP("skybox/deep_lf.bmp");
    _skybox[1] = __loadMipmappedTexture(image);
    image = loadBMP("skybox/deep_bk.bmp");
    _skybox[2] = __loadMipmappedTexture(image);
    image = loadBMP("skybox/deep_rt.bmp");
    _skybox[3] = __loadMipmappedTexture(image);
    image = loadBMP("skybox/deep_up.bmp");
    _skybox[4] = __loadMipmappedTexture(image);
    image = loadBMP("skybox/deep_dn.bmp");
    _skybox[5] = __loadMipmappedTexture(image);
    delete image;

}

void handleResize(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0, (double)w / (double)h, 1.0, 100.0);
    glViewport (0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void mouseMovement(int x, int y) {

    if (leftMouseButton == true)
    {
        GLfloat diffx = (x-lastx)/20; //check the difference between the current x and the last x position
        GLfloat diffy = (y-lasty)/20; //check the difference between the current y and the last y position
        lastx = x; //set lastx to the current x position
        lasty = y; //set lasty to the current y position

        xrot += (float) diffy; //set the xrot to xrot with the addition of the difference in the y position
        yrot += (float) diffx;    //set the xrot to yrot with the addition of the difference in the x position
    }
    else if( leftMouseButton == false)
    {
        GLfloat diffx = x-lastx; //check the difference between the current x and the last x position
        GLfloat diffy = y-lasty; //check the difference between the current y and the last y position
        lastx = x; //set lastx to the current x position
        lasty = y; //set lasty to the current y position
    }
}

void mouseButtons(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
    if ((state == GLUT_DOWN) && (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)) 
    {
        leftMouseButton = true;
    }

    else if ((state == GLUT_DOWN) && (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON)) 
    {
        leftMouseButton = false;
    }
}

void drawGrid(float size, float step)
{
    // disable lighting
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    glColor3f(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
    for(float i=step; i <= size; i+= step)
    {
        glVertex3f(-size, 0,  i);   // lines parallel to X-axis
        glVertex3f( size, 0,  i);
        glVertex3f(-size, 0, -i);   // lines parallel to X-axis
        glVertex3f( size, 0, -i);

        glVertex3f( i, 0, -size);   // lines parallel to Z-axis
        glVertex3f( i, 0,  size);
        glVertex3f(-i, 0, -size);   // lines parallel to Z-axis
        glVertex3f(-i, 0,  size);
    }

    // x-axis
    glColor3f(0.5f, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(-size, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f( size, 0, 0);

    // z-axis
    glColor3f(0,0,0.5f);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, -size);
    glVertex3f(0, 0,  size);

    glEnd();

    // enable lighting back
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
}

void keyboard (unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    float xrotrad, yrotrad;
    switch(key) {
    case 'a':
        xrot += 1;
        if(xrot > 360) xrot -= 360;
        break;
    case 'w':
        xrot -= 1;
        if(xrot < -360) xrot += 360;
        break;
    case 'z':   
        yrotrad = (yrot / 180 * PI);
        xrotrad = (xrot / 180 * PI); 
        xpos += float(sin(yrotrad));
        zpos -= float(cos(yrotrad));
        ypos -= float(sin(xrotrad));
        break;
    case 's':   
        yrotrad = (yrot / 180 * PI);
        xrotrad = (xrot / 180 * PI); 
        xpos -= float(sin(yrotrad));
        zpos += float(cos(yrotrad));
        ypos += float(sin(xrotrad));
        break;
    case 'd':
        yrot += 1;
        if (yrot >360) yrot -= 360;
        break;
    case 'q':
        yrot -= 1;
        if (yrot < -360)yrot += 360;
        break;

    case 27:
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
}

void camera (void) {
    glRotatef(xrot,1.0,0.0,0.0);  //rotate our camera on teh x-axis (left and right)
    glRotatef(yrot,0.0,1.0,0.0);  //rotate our camera on the y-axis (up and down)
    glTranslated(-xpos,-ypos,-zpos); //translate the screen to the position of our camera
}

void drawScene() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    GLfloat lightKa[] = {.0f, .0f, .0f, 1.0f};      // ambient light
    GLfloat lightKd[] = {.9f, .9f, .9f, 1.0f};      // diffuse light
    GLfloat lightKs[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};               // specular light
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, lightKa);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightKd);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, lightKs);

    // position the light
    float lightPos[4] = {0, 10, 10, 0};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos);

    camera();

    //call the skybox
    // Store the current matrix
    glPushMatrix();

    // Reset and transform the matrix.
    glLoadIdentity();

    /* EDIT: I really dont know how to set gluLookAt, I guess it should be the camera positions??? */
    gluLookAt(
        0.0,0.0,0.0,
        0.1, 0.0, 0.1,
        0.0,1.0,0.0);

    // Enable/Disable features
    glPushAttrib(GL_ENABLE_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(false);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    // Just in case we set all vertices to white.
    glColor4f(1,1,1,1);

    // Render the front quad
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _skybox[0]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f( -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f( -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f );
    glEnd();

    // Render the left quad
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _skybox[1]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f );
    glEnd();

    // Render the back quad
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _skybox[2]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f( -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f( -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f );

    glEnd();

    // Render the right quad
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _skybox[3]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f( -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f( -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f( -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f( -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f );
    glEnd();

    // Render the top quad
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _skybox[4]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f( -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f( -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f );
    glEnd();

    // Render the bottom quad
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _skybox[5]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f( -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f( -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f );
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f );
    glEnd();

    // Restore enable bits and matrix
    glPopAttrib();
    glPopMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glDepthMask(true);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    drawGrid(20, 1);

    glutSwapBuffers(); //swap the buffers

}

void update(int value) {
    angle++; //increase the angle
    glutPostRedisplay(); //Tell GLUT that the display has changed

    //Tell GLUT to call update again in 25 milliseconds
    glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 800);

    glutCreateWindow("Block Position");
    initRendering();

    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutIdleFunc(drawScene);

    glutReshapeFunc(handleResize);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouseMovement); 
    glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0); //Add a timer
    glutMouseFunc(mouseButtons);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with minimal rendering, like no lightning, no face culling, just triangles in white color. So if you see white then at least your camera position is probably OK. Then you can enable culling, if all disappears then this is your problem - normals are in wrong directions. Then if all is OK, enable lighting, then texturing - and always check what changes.

so dont look at it too hard, but eliminate complexity - even check if simple trianlge will show up in the expected position.

Comment: I excluded the code for drawing a simple triangle already, that always seems to work. Like I said it does draw the grid and the triangle, I've disabled everything and still it does not work. Thanks!

Comment: Its hard to tell exactly what is the cause, one thing that looks strange is how you setup your camera matrix and the use of gluLookAt(). It looks similar how its done here: http://sidvind.com/wiki/Skybox_tutorial, but as you can see it actually uses camera position as center point, so maybe change it to: gluLookAt(0.0,0.0,0.0, xpos, ypos, zpos, 0.0,1.0,0.0);?

Comment: I changed that to 0.0f because I was testing it with a simpel triangle, I have changed it now and it still does not work. I indeed followed the tutorial you mentioned. Thanks, for your time maybe something else is wrong...

Answer (score 2):

If nothing is appearing at all, it may be because the sky box isn't in the scene because it's being `culled` (or not rendered) onto the screen.

In your code you specify `100.0` for the `zFar`:

```
gluPerspective(45.0, (double)w / (double)h, 1.0, 100.0);
```

Change the `zFar` value to accommodate for the size of the sky box (say 500.0) and it should appear.